# SEO questions limit

Tags: discussion, questions

It looks like anything is asked related to helping SEO.

Have a look at this question: [Is it SEO safe to put <span> inside <a> element?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/98113/is-it-seo-safe-to-put-span-inside-a-element)

This question isn't about SEO, it's about semantic HTML.

Clearly the questioner needs to learn HTML. There are many other questions like this, where if the user was directed to learn HTML which is one of the most basic things they'd be better of.

Personally think these questions are of very low quality and will bring little to no value at all.

Thoughts?

Comment: The question is whether tag usage effects SEO.   The answer is "clearly not," but that doesn't make it a question that isn't about SEO.

Comment: As for "little to no value," that depends on whether other people or going to have the same question.     To you and me it looks like a very basic question with an obvious answer, but I'm often surprised by which questions get a large number of views over the years.

Answer (score 3):

I feel the same as you, but you must understand that this is Q&A site, and that  users here are with big variety of knowledge. This question might be low quality to some users, or easy to answer to some, but as the OP concerned (clearly he doesn't know the answer, so he asks the question) it's unknown territory.

So, it's a legit seo question (maybe a stupid one in my book) but it's still not too broad and too chatty/spammy to be concidered as offtopic or administrators to close the question. And yeah, it's not a duplicate also.

Comment: I agree however my point is that the op could be directed to learn html as that will solve his problem. And as an example stop the user from coming back and asking if b tag is allowed inside a p tag and its seo implications etc. Semantic markup is best practice. In SO they have a similar tendency where op is directed to self educate on basic things first or at least describe what they've tried and or the problems they're facing.

Comment: @AbuNooh I have to stop, hold my breath, and then dive in to answer questions sometimes. For me, sometimes I do not know how to answer such basic questions. However, this is a big opportunity to mentor a noobie like we were likely mentored when we started. It is also an opportunity to point to references that will help the OP grow on their own. IT was more complicated when I started since most everything had to be coded in a low level programming language or close to it. No DBMS, no objects, no scripts, no GUI, nothing. Today, with so many options, where to start is much tougher. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc agreed. I think with the ubitiquosness of cms etc, anyone is able to jump into creating websites and then the problem arises when things go wrong and then they have to start to fix things from ground up.